# How to get the value text from a QR code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qr-code

I am trying to get the value text from my QR code (`myqr`). I have a submit button where the qr code is submitted. How do I get the value text from the qr code?

```js
$(document).ready(function qr1() {
  var code = document.getElementById("qrdiv");
  code.textContent = qr;
  var text = code.textContent;
  $("#qr1").submit(function(c) {;
    c.preventDefault();
    var answer = $("#photo").val();
    if (answer === "myqr") {
      qr = 1;
      alert("YES!");
    } else {
      console.log("NO!");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
  <form id="qr1">
    <div class="center">
      <img id="image" class="media" />
    </div>
    <input id="photo" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
    <input type="submit" id="answerbtn1" value="submit1" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: *"How do I get the value text from the qr code"* What is a QR code text value?

Comment: the qr code contains just text - myqr

Comment: Why you have a `;` after `.submit(function(c){;` ? (OT) it's strange you used `c` as an argument to describe actually: `Event`

Comment: Why do you have `qr1` in `$(document).ready(function qr1(){`?

Comment: On submit simply alert your `answer` variable to test... and you'll see why you cannot make it work. Again what value you're trying to get?

Comment: the qr div is in my html page

Comment: What is this line? `code.textContent = qr;` ? Why don't you use jQuery `$('#qrdiv').text( qr ); `

Comment: So? Have you tried to alert `answer`? what do you get? :) Your question it totally misleading. You need a plugin do decode a QR code and get the QR code value, not the image name.

Comment: the article posted in the answer was what I was looking for, thanks for your help